# How can i check whether my openid logging system is accepting and processing yahoo openids?

Tags: openid, yahoo-oauth

How can i check whether my openid logging system is accepting and processing yahoo openids?

Is the simple account where we have yahoo mail or yahoo homepage is an openid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yahoo accounts are not OpenID enabled by default but you can easily make them so by visiting [this site.](http://openid.yahoo.com/)

Comment: I don't think this is true any more.